# instantiate using an inherited generic type

Tags: java

I have the following case

```
public class ResponseType <T> {
  private ParameterizedTypeReference<HttpResponse<T>> type;

  private ResponseType() {
    this.type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<HttpResponse<T>>() {};
  }

  public static <T> ResponseType<T> create() {
    return new ResponseType<T>();
  }
}
```

When I call `ReponseType.<MyClass>create()` where how can I construct a `ParameterizedTypeReference<HttpResponse<MyClass>>`?

Currently if I call this, the type will be `ParameterizedTypeReference<HttpResponse<T>>`

What I want to do is to call

```
restTemplate.exchange(
    ...,
    responseType.getType()
);
```

where `responseType = ResponseType.create()` or `resonseType = ResponseType.<MyClass>create()`

instead of

```
restTemplate.exchange(
    ...,
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<HttpResponse<MyClass>>() {}
);
```

Comment: You will need to inject the instance of `ParameterizedTypeReference<HttpResponse<T>>` as a parameter.

Comment: @AndyTurner Can you elaborate a bit on that? Does that mean that the "static T" doesn't come into play when calling the ctor?

Comment: I updated my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating in the constructor that is called by create() witht he type T and storing inside the class as 'type'

If its public:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<HttpResponse<MyClass>> obj = ReponseType.<MyClass>create().type;
```